# How do you say "he caught a fish?"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario-técnico

"Pescar" means "to fish", but which verb would be used to indicate that somebody caught a fish? "Captar", "atrapar", "coger"?

Comment: Las ideas, las sensaciones y el agua se "captan". Las personas y los animales se "capturan". .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se suele usar con mayor frecuencia el verbo `atrapar`. Puedes encontrar varios ejemplos de uso con una búsqueda rápida en Google como este artículo ["Cómo **atrapar** peces sin una caña de pescar"](http://es.wikihow.com/atrapar-peces-sin-una-ca%C3%B1a-de-pescar) o este [hilo de wordreference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/atrapar-pescar-un-pez.3098674/?hl=es), que discute el uso del término (resumiendo el contenido de ese hilo, que se adapta muy bien como respuesta a tu pregunta, **el mejor verbo es por supuesto "pescar"; después de este, podría usarse "atrapar"**. El hilo no discute "coger", aunque sí "pillar").

Puedes usar también "coger" (salvo que estés en [ciertos países de latinoamérica](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/8749/5481) y quieras evitar el término).

> Ayer atrapé un pez *así* de grande
>
> Ayer cogí un pez *así* de grande

Como bien apunta Carlos en los comentarios, "atrapar" tiene matiz de "capturar" (que es realmente lo que hacemos al pescar: capturar peces sacándolos del agua). Coger, que puede tener connotaciones más similares a "asir" en este caso, sería la opción menos buena para sustituir a "pescar".

No se usa "[captar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7M88XDA)", que tiene un sentido más de atraer

> **Atraer** a alguien o **ganar su voluntad** o afecto

Nadie dice que "capta un pez", porque significaría que "percibe un pez" o que ha conseguido "[engatusar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FMaToZa)" al pez.

Es también interesante que "[pescar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SmXLO5X)" se ha convertido en un sinónimo de coloquial para ciertas acciones

> **Pescar**
>
> 4. tr. coloq. Coger, agarrar o tomar cualquier cosa.

Sin embargo, si lo que buscas es sustituir el propio *"pescar"* la mejor opción es **atrapar**, ya que los peces son atrapados en redes, anzuelos o por otros métodos, capturados y sacados del agua de esta forma (convirtiéndose entonces en *[pescados](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12052/5481)*).

Quizá merzca

Comment: Nice answer, but if you say "ayer cogí un pez" it may mean that the fish was in the floor, still, and you just took it and lifted it up. If you say "ayer atrapé un pez", then it means that the fish was alive and moving and you made an effort to catch it. But obviously, as Diego says the best option is "ayer pesqué un pez".

Comment: I do not agree with @CarlosAlejo and this may be because of regional differences. "Ayer cogí un pez" is perfectly understood in Colombia and it is obvious that it was from the water with some fishing equipment. "Atrapé" will also be understood but you will sound like you are in a school play or at a soup opera (not natural). The most common words used around here are _agarré, cogí, saqué y pesqué_

Answer (score 5):

I support Diego's answer but I want to add two more possibilities:

> Ayer pescó un pez.
>
> Ayer agarró un pez.

The second one might be local to Mexico, I'm not sure.

Comment: Both are ok in Colombia too.